# No puedo importar libreria desde .py pero si desde terminal

Tags: python, rutas

He instalado un par de librerías (`Piexif`, `pyexiv2`) desde terminal con los siguientes comandos:

```
sudo pip install piexif

sudo apt-get install python-pyexiv2
```

Por ende, sus importaciones son así

```
import piexif
import pyexiv2
```

Pero me arroja error, que no encontró el modulo.
Decidí probar importándolo desde terminal con

```
sudo python
import piexif
import pyexiv2
```

Y no arrojó errores.

He leído y en algunos casos es problema de `PATH`, entonces ejecuté este código:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
for path in sys.path:
    print path
```

Lo cual me arroja esto:

```
/home/yehad/Escritorio/HardDrones/Proyecto identificacion de
vegetacion/Pruebas/Inspire
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/thinning-1.2.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg
/usr/lib/python2.7 /usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/home/yehad/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0
```

Y las librerías están justamente en `/home/yehad/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`, por lo que ese no sería el problema.

[image: Imagen error:]

[image: Imagen Libreria Oficial]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que leo, tienes instalada una de las librerías (piexif) con los permisos de root, por ende, cualquier usuario con menos privilegios (todos) pueden no tener acceso a esta.

```
sudo -H pip install piexif  # Updated from @toledano tip, sudo -H will not change owner permisions
```

Solución, instalarla para el usuario activo con el param "--user":

```
pip install piexif --user
```

Otra opción sería habilitar y reestablecer los permisos en la carpeta donde se ubican las librerías, que quizá hayan perdido la propiedad de yehad y por eso no puedas acceder a ella.

```
sudo chown yehad -R /home/yehad/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
sudo chmod 0664 -R /home/yehad/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Comment: Hola Aaron! gracias por responder, seguí tu consejo y ejecute `pip install piexif --user` y me aparece que ya está instalado. Luego ejecuté también las dos lineas para habilitar y reestablecer los permisos, y no arrojo ningun error. Pero el problema persiste, no se puede importar desde el IDLE (es sublime text en este caso) ni tampoco cargando el archivo.py desde terminal. 

Decidí desinstalar la librería con `sudo pip uninstall piexif` y reiniciar. Luego ejecuté en el terminal `pip install piexif --user` y me dice permiso denegado.

Comment: Luego de que me dijera permiso denegado, ejecuté las dos lineas de comandos para habilitar y reestablecer, luego instalé denuevo con SUDO y pude importar. Luego me arroja error de sus funciones. Añadí dos imágenes del error.

Comment: Le cambié el nombre al archivo a piexif_prueba.py y ahora el error volvió al original, que es no poder importar el modulo de la libreria. es sumamente raro.

Comment: El problema era el siguiente: tenia un archivo .py con el nombre piexif.py y tenia conflicto con el original de la libreria. SOLUCIONADO.

Comment: @AaronGiovannini, cuando uses `pip`  se crea un directorio `cache`, por lo tanto, al usarlo en combinación con `sudo` debes asegurarte de usar la opción `-H` o `--set-home` para que dicho directorio no se vuelva inutilizable. En Ubuntu, esta opción **no es default**.

Comment: @toledano, gracias por el tip.

Answer (score 0):

Después de varias semanas encontré la solución realizandolo de esta forma:

```
sudo chmod 0664 -R /home/yehad/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```